How to define a group from a commutative ring in cubical library?
so I want to use the library cubical to get the quotient of two groups, ℚ / ℤ, using the cubical library. The problem is that first I need to show that ℚ is a group.
Digging around I found that the rationals already have a definition as a commutative ring inside cubical, so I would like to use portions of that structure to recover the group operations.
I tried something like this:
{-# OPTIONS  --cubical  #-}

import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as Eq
open Eq using (_≡_; refl; sym; trans; cong; subst)
open Eq.≡-Reasoning
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ; zero; suc; _+_; _*_; _∸_; _≤_; s≤s; z≤n)
open import Data.Nat.Properties using
  (+-assoc; +-identityˡ; +-identityʳ; *-assoc; *-identityˡ; *-identityʳ; *-distribʳ-+; *-distribˡ-+; *-comm; +-comm)
open import Function using (_∘_)
open import Data.Product using (_×_; ∃; ∃-syntax; proj₁; proj₂) renaming (_,_ to ⟨_,_⟩)
open import Data.Rational.Base using (ℚ)
open import Data.Integer.Base using (ℤ)
open import Cubical.Algebra.Group.QuotientGroup using (_/_)
open import Cubical.Algebra.Group.Subgroup using (NormalSubgroup)
open import Cubical.Algebra.Group.Base using (group; IsGroup)
open import Cubical.Algebra.CommRing.Instances.Rationals using (ℚCommRing)
open import Cubical.Algebra.CommRing.Base using (CommRing)
open Cubical.Algebra.CommRing.Base.CommRingStr

postulate h : IsGroup (0r (proj₂ ℚCommRing)) (Cubical.Algebra.CommRing.Base.CommRingStr._+_ (proj₂ ℚCommRing)) (-_ (proj₂ ℚCommRing))
postulate ℚGroup : group (proj₁ ℚCommRing) (0r (proj₂ ℚCommRing)) (Cubical.Algebra.CommRing.Base.CommRingStr._+_ (proj₂ ℚCommRing)) (-_ (proj₂ ℚCommRing)) h
-- postulate qqq : NormalSubgroup ℤ
-- postulate π : ℚ → ℚ / ℤ

but is not working. Im just doing trial and error at this point, since I couldnt find any examples on how to use this library or how to actually use the Group or CommRing modules. I know that ℚCommRing has enough structure to get a group, but I dont know how to recover all that information and use it to get something that at least compiles with postulates.

CommRing→AbGroup, AbGroup→Group
